# Python: How do I assign 2 values I return from a function with 1 input as values outside the function?

Tags: python, function, scope, return, tuples

I'm starting out in python and thought it'd be a good exercise to try to build a function that determines whether an input passed to it is an integer, and if so whether it's positive. At a later stage I plan to reference that function from within a mathematical function that only accepts positive integers.

Anyway, this is the function I built:

```
def is_ok(x):           #checks if x is a positive integer
    is_int = False
    is_pos = False
    if type(x) == int:
        is_int = True   # if it's an integer, continue to test if >0
        if x > 0:
            is_pos = True
        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass
    return is_int, is_pos
```

as you can see, it gets one argument (the value to be tested) and returns a tuple of Trues and Falses.

Now, I don't know how to use the tuple outside the function... for instance, if I try to pass a number through the function and assign variable the values received, I get an error. I mean something like:

```
is_int, is_pos = is_ok(y)
```

y being some number, for example. this produces an error on run.

So basically what I'm trying to understand is how to do the following:
function A accepts a value as its sole input ===> runs it through the is_ok(x) function ===> function A gets the tuple produced by is_ok() function and uses if/elifs to produce different results depending on the value of the tuple.

example for function A:

```
def get_value():
    z = input("insert value" ")
    is_ok(z)
    if (is_int,is_pos) == (True, True):
        print z**2
    elif (is_int,is_pos) == (False, False):
        print "Please enter an integer"
        get_value()
    elif (is_int, is_pos) == (True, False):
        print "Please enter an positive integer"
        get_value()
    else:
        print "something is wrong"
```

Help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

======================
EDIT: late addition

when I run this on input 7 for example (any positive integer for that matter):

```
def is_ok(x):           #checks if x is a positive integer
    is_int = False
    is_pos = False
    if type(x) == int:
        is_int = True   # if it's an integer, continue to test if >0
        if x > 0:
            is_pos = True
        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass
    return is_int, is_pos

#is_int, is_pos = is_ok(y)
#print is_ok(y)
#print is_int
#print is_pos

#is_ok(7)

def get_value():
    z = input("insert value ")
    is_int, is_pos = is_ok(z)
    if (is_int,is_pos) == (True, True):
        print z**2
    elif (is_int,is_pos) == (False, False):
        print "Please enter an integer"
        get_value()
    elif (is_int, is_pos) == (True, False):
        print "Please enter an positive integer"
        get_value()
    else:
        print "something is wrong"

get_value()
```

I get:

49
(True, False)

First Q: why False?
Second Q: if false, why did it return what it should have for True, True
Third Q: why did it print the tuple? No print statement

More help? :)

Comment: What error do you get? The example call you show is correct.  However, in `get_value()`, you fail to assign the return value of `is_ok()` to `is_int` and `is_pos`.

Comment: thanks for spotting that. basically when i pass a positive integer the tuple i get is (True, False), for starters. BTW now I also spot a problem I'll have when the user tries to pass a string

Comment: also kindly notice my edit. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As chepner mentioned in the comments, you're on the right track but you're throwing away your results!

Personally, I wouldn't do what you're doing, I would check it separately for each thing (as opposed to using one function to check two facts about a variable and return each fact). But if you WANT to do it your way, here's what you'd need to do:

```
def is_ok(x):           #checks if x is a positive integer
    is_int = False
    is_pos = False
    if type(x) == int:
        is_int = True   # if it's an integer, continue to test if >0
        if x > 0:
            is_pos = True
        else:
            pass
    else:
        pass
    return is_int, is_pos

def get_value():
    z = input("insert value: ")
    is_int, is_pos = is_ok(z)
    if (is_int,is_pos) == (True, True): # could also do `if all(is_int,is_pos):`
        print z**2
    elif (is_int,is_pos) == (False, False):
        print "Please enter an integer"
        get_value()
    elif (is_int, is_pos) == (True, False):
        print "Please enter an positive integer"
        get_value()
    else:
        print "something is wrong"
```

If I were you, I'd write something like:

```
def get_value():
    while True:
        z = input("Insert value: ") # DON'T DO THIS, INPUT() IS BADDDDD IN PYTHON2
        # instead do:
        ## try: z = int(raw_input("Insert value: "))
        ## except ValueError:
        ##     print("Please provide an integer")
        ##     continue
        # this also FORCES z to be an integer, so isinstance(z,int) is ALWAYS TRUE
        is_int = isinstance(z,int)
        is_pos = is_int and z>0 # this will keep you from throwing an exception if
                                # you can't compare z>0 because z isn't int
        if is_int and is_pos:
            print z**2
        elif is_int:
            print "Please provide an integer"
            continue
        else:
            print "Integer must be positive"
            continue
        # nothing can ever get to that last else block you had.
```

The reason we don't use `input` in Python2 is that it executes whatever you write out as Python code. If I entered `import os; for file in os.listdir("C:/windows/system32"): os.remove(file)` it would delete every file in `C:\Windows\System32`. I don't think I have to tell you why that's bad! :)

Comment: good stuff @adsmith, good stuff. Also I think kindda important to know about the pitfalls of input :D
Thanks a lot!

Comment: would you mind looking at the edit i made to the original post (on the bottom) and see if you can understand why I got those outputs?
thanks again :)

Comment: @Optimesh I copied your code line for line and I don't get the same output as you do. I think you need to look over your local code again :)

Comment: Strange! thanks anyway :) (and yea, looks better now. mind boggling!!)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return two values, you can return them as a list like this:
`return [value1, value2]`

If your goal is to validate input to make sure it's a positive integer, this is how I'd do it:

```
def get_value():
    while True:
        try:
            z = int(raw_input("insert value: "))
            if z > 0:
                return z
            else:
                print "Please enter a positive integer"
        except ValueError:
            print "Please enter an integer"
```